# How to connect two FPGA boards achieving speed in tens of Gbps?

Tags: fpga, connector, xilinx

I want to connect two FPGA boards e.g. B1 to B2 such that the link could transfer enough data per second from B1 to B2. What i mean is that the **link between the two boards should NOT be the bottleneck**. So that i could test the throughput of the FPGA on B2.

The data transferred is Layer 2, Layer 3 packets. The FPGA is of the Xilinx.
Probably I need more speed provided by PCIe 2.0 i.e 5 Gbps. Can I use Ethernet cable Cat 6a, Cat 7 or above for this purpose? Or Can I use Very High Density Cable Interconnect (VHDCI) connector between two FPGA boards as it can provide 80 Gbps speed? Or any other link that could provide higher Gbps speed between Xilinx FPGA boards?

Comment: Depends on what kind of physical interfaces you have on the FPGA. If they have 10G or 40G Ethernet that sounds suitable.

Comment: Are you designing a board or using off-the-shelf dev boards? If you're using off-the-shelf boards, it would be extremely helpful to know which ones, what FPGAs they have, and what interfaces they have.

Comment: Depending on the FPGA they tend to come with either very high speed SERDES interfaces (the fastest currently offer 58 gigabit/second using 4PAM), 10 GbE, 40GbE, 100GbE interfaces, etc. Pick your poison.

Comment: 8 Lane PCIe Gen 2 will give you a throughput of close to 30Gbps.

Comment: Thank you all seniors for your replies. I am just new to hardware implementation. Software implementation is easier. So means we should either have high speed Ethernet interface to use higher versions of Ethernet cables like Cat 6a or Cat 7, or we should have PCIe interface as Mr. Tom Carpenter said. But unfortunately the FPGA boards I have, have only Ethernet interface capable of 1 Gbps and NO PCI...

Comment: So it means, in my FPGA boards, the link between them must be the bottleneck. It would not transfer the data with enough speed to saturate the FPGA on board B2. Any other solution or we have to buy new boards?

Comment: If you are using Xilinx FPGAs you could go for a AXI Chip2Chip bridge with as many gigabit lanes (Aurora) as you require for your application to meet throughput requirements. The advantage would be that you can access modules on each FPGA via normal AXI write/read commands without any additional fuzz like packing data into Ethernet frames etc..